# Newly created visionOS project won’t compile: 'Missing package product 'RealityKitContent'

Tags: xcode, visionos

I created a new visionOS project in Xcode. I chose RealityKit as the immersive space renderer, windowed, and mixed. I create the project, and I'm getting a build error 'No such module 'RealityKitContent'
The error says 'Missing package product 'RealityKitContent'
I am using visionOS version 1.1, with Xcode 15.3, M1 Macbook pro, Mac OS 14.4.

I tried adding the RealityKitContent content package directly using package manager, but I can't find it.

EDIT:
Changed the build location from legacy to unique in xcode location settings and it worked!

Comment: You haven’t provided anything relevant. What error are you getting? What does your environment look like? Xcode version, OS, Intel vs Silicon mac?

Comment: Added details in edit

Comment: Are you sure you are building for visionos? Not visionos for ipad or ios.

Comment: yes i'm sure. I just created the default vision os app from xcode

Comment: I routinely see that error when I haven't tried to build a brand new project yet. Does it go away when you command-B?

Comment: Nope it doesn’t build

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. I've seen this show up a few times and the restart clears it.

Comment: I've been trying for a week. Nothing is working. I am unable to create the app

Comment: Managed to fix it! see edit

Comment: That’s great! Please add an answer that says that, and accept your own answer. That will show the question as answered, for anyone who hasn’t read the discussion.